# how to know whether a UITextView has a focus or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I know the `becomeFirstResponder` method to set a focus on a control, but how to know whether that control (for ex. `UITextView`) is currently having focus on it or not ?

EDIT: the problem is that I want (for example) to change the background color of the UITextView when it receives focus, where should I put the isFirstResponder call exactly ?  should I use notifications in this case ?

thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If there isn't, subclass UITextView and add an ivar/property to that effect. Then override -becomeFirstResponder and set the flag.

Comment: oh yes, didn't pay attention to such property, yes there is actually a property named isFirstResponder .. you can answer the question so you may be voted up.

Comment: but the problem is that I want (for example) to change the background color of the UITextView when it receives focus, where should I put the isFirstResponder call exactly ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
if([txtView isFirstResponder]){
     //Has Focus
} else {
     //Lost Focus
}
```

This is UITextView's delegate method,

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)aTextView{
    //Has Focus
    return YES;
}
```

This is lost focus

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
        //Lost Focus
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that I want (for example) to change the background color of the UITextView when it receives focus, where should I put the isFirstResponder call exactly ?

Comment: Don't forget to register some object as the text view's delegate (usually the view controller owning the text view's parent view)

Comment: `shouldChangeTextInRange` with the line break seems a weird method to detect focus loss. This doesn't catch all possible situations where a text view can lose focus, does it?

Answer (score 6):

Use the UITextField delegate methods. When textField got focus the(bacame first responder)

`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;` will be fired,

and when it lost focus

`- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;` will be fired.